# Is there an Optimized Norm-Conserving Vanderbilt (ONCV) pseudopotential of Eu atom?

Tags: density-functional-theory, pseudopotentials

I'm currently searching for an Optimized Norm-Conserving Vanderbilt (ONCV) pseudopotential of Eu, which has a localized f-orbital. But no matter how much I search online, I can't find it.

There is an [online repository](http://www.quantum-simulation.org/potentials/sg15_oncv/upf/) of other atoms that have a ONCV pseudopotential, but some of the rare earth elements such as Eu, Lanthanides etc. don't have one.

Does anyone have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: after posting my answer, I noticed you have asked this question also in the QE users forum and your question got a response there. That response is better than my answer posted here since that contains both scalar relativistic and full relativistic version, uses GGA (PBE) instead of LDA (PZ), contains `<PP_PSWFC>` sections so that you will be able to do projection (pdos) calculation, and also the PP I referred to is more than a decade old. For reference, [here](https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/users/2024-February/051239.html) is the answer to your question by Lorenzo Paulatto in QE users forum.

Since you mentioned SG15 database and upf format, I am assuming you are looking for the pseudopotential in the UPF format.

In the Quantum ESPRESSO's official pseudopotential page, they have this [Hartwigesen-Goedecker-Hutter](https://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/legacy_tables/hartwigesen-goedecker-hutter-pp) pseudopotential tables where you have the pseudopotential of $\mathrm{Eu}$. This is the [direct link](https://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/legacy_tables/hartwigesen-goedecker-hutter-pp/eu) to the $\mathrm{Eu}$ pseudopotential page and this is the [direct link](https://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/upf_files/Eu.pz-sp-hgh.UPF) to your desired pseudopotential in UPF format.

Details:

> Eu.pz-sp-hgh.UPF
>
> Pseudopotential type: NORMCONS
>
> Method: Goedecker-Hartwigsen-Hutter-Teter
>
> Functional type: Perdew-Zunger
> (LDA) exch-corr Semi-core state in valence non relativistic
>
> Origin: Hartwigsen-Goedeker-Hutter PP
>
> Author: Goedecker/Hartwigsen/Hutter/Teter Generated in analytical, separable
> form. Converted from CPMD format using cpmd2upf v.5.0.1. Uploaded by
> marsamos Classification unverified

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know that the answer was posted in QE forum. But your answer was also helpful enough. Anyway,  is there a way to check in real time whether my question has been answered? I couldn't realize that there was a reply...

Comment: @Y.S.Lym yes, you can turn on mail notification in QE user forum's [option](https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/mailman/options/users) page. You can choose between daily digest option or instant notification option. There are option for other settings too.

Comment: @ Abdul Muhaymin  Thanks!! I got a lot of help from you!